# Reuse cells between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have two ViewControllers with `UITableViews` that both have the same custom cells. I have wired the cells with `IBOutlets` to properties in sublclasses of UITableViewCell.

These classes look like this:

```
class CarIdentityCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var carName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var carImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Since those cells appear in both views, I'd like to reuse them. However, since the wiring is made from the interface builder, I'm not sure how to do it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design the cell in a xib file, not the storyboard prototype, and register that same nib with each table view’s reuse identifier.